# Rails iOS Post Error

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, json

In rails server, I do this

```
rails generate scaffold hub code:string name:string desc:string
rake db:migrate
rails server
```

And in my iOS Project, I need to do a post on hub to create a new hub, my code is

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"code" : @"12ab", @"name" : @"JONAS", @"desc" : @"FOI?"};

manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

[manager POST:@"localhost:3000/hubs" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    UIAlertView *alertInfo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Informação" message:@"Hub criado" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertInfo show];

} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    UIAlertView *alertInfo = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Informação" message:@"Erro" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alertInfo show];
}];
```

I receiver error code 422

What is wrong?

Comment: "422 - Unprocessable Entity" should you be using POST:@"http://localhost:3000/hub" instead of POST:@"localhost:3000/hubs" (notice the extra 's' is removed) ?

Answer (score 0):

Try change your localhost:3000/hubs to

> http://localhost:3000/hubs